# How to solve the (b) circuit?

Tags: transistors, led, zener

[image]

In circuit b there is a Zener, LED and transistor the voltage of base I assume is 12 V - 6.2 V = 5.8 V so I guess V<sub>e</sub> is V<sub>b</sub> - V<sub>be</sub> = 5.8 V - 0.7 V = 5.1 V but I can't guess the current which is passing the LED.
Then can I guess the voltage of 200 Ω?

Example: 6.2 - 0.7 = 5.5.

How can I solve it?

Comment: You're well on your way! The voltage across the 200Ω resistor would indeed be 5.5 Volts. To solve the question further, however, you would need to have a beta (or gain) value for the pnp transistor. Does your question provide any more information?

Comment: Is your Ve calculation correct? This is a pnp bipolar.

Comment: Well beta is given 100 and is there any problem at Ve?

Comment: Is the voltage of Vbe 0.7V?

Comment: No..............

Comment: Then How can i guess the value of Vbe most of people said 0.6 or 0.7

Comment: See my first comment, this is a PNP transistor.

Comment: Oh im sorry i get it then i need to add 0.7 instead - 0.7

Answer (score 0):

From the question:

> Can I guess the voltage of 200 Ω? (Example, 6.2 - 0.7 = 5.5).

This is correct. From that you can work out the current through the 200 Ω resistor and when you have the β value you can work out the LED current.

From the comments:

> ... then I need to add 0.7 instead - 0.7 ...

When you are making statements like this you need to make it clear where the reference is. If we are measuring from GND then, yes, you add the voltage of the base-emitter drop.

Comment: Tks for your answer